# Getting errors on installing new pod file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoapods

There are **pod** files installed in my project.

Now I want to add new pod file for '***PhotoPickerPlus***' , but I am getting duplicate symbols errors and warnings as seen in following screenshot ;

[image]

I have tried to install pod file by using

**pod install**

It is successfully installed. I have also inclueded all required frameworks.

My pod file is as follows ;

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'ARGenericTableViewController', '~> 1.0.0'
#pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 1.6'
pod 'TBXML', '~> 1.5'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 2.0beta4'
#pod 'FlurrySDK', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.5.4'
#pod 'PSTCollectionView', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'BSKeyboardControls', '~> 2.2'
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.5.4'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'MKMapView+AttributionView', '~> 0.1.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.13.0'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.9.0'
pod 'JASidePanels'
#pod 'ARChromeActivity', '~> 1.0.1'
#pod 'TUSafariActivity', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'REComposeViewController', '~> 2.3.1'
pod 'iRate', '~> 1.9.3'
pod 'PhotoPickerPlus', '~> 2.2'
pod 'UIPhotoGallery', :podspec => 'UIPhotoGallery.podspec'
But I am getting errors after installing this file.
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you try `Clean` and `Clean Build Folder` actions? Or restart your Xcode?

Comment: @AnushaK yes i have tried it. But no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your `Other Linker Flags` inside the `Build Settings` inside your project is set wrong. Click on your Project inside `Project Navigator`. If you select your app on `PROJECT` your `Build Settings` should look like this

[image]

Inside my project I also deleted everything inside `Other Linker Flags` but maybe it works for you if you insert this

[image]

And of course never forget cleaning after these steps.

Answer (score 1):

In you Project Settings, Check target's "Build Phases"'s "Compile source" section. Make sure there are no duplicate copies.

BTW, These errors are generated by https://github.com/gameclosure/trademob which is not even in your pod file.

So again, verify your project settings. Probably you are trying to add pod file to existing project.